# what might cause macOS app to render all blurry on retina macOS

Tags: xcode, macos, uikit

I have a problem in my existing macOS project.
My windows/views render all blurry on a retina Mac when I run it.
It look perfectly fine in Xcode when working with the storyboard.

If I add a new window to my existing app it looks like this (all blurry):

[image]

while when I do a new project it looks like this (perfectly sharp):

[image]

i am searching for what might cause this for hours now but am still without a clue. 
Does anyone know what might influences the rendering of my macOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to set

```
NSHighResolutionCapable
```

to

```
yes
```

in my projects **plist** file. 
Not sure tho what exactly is different on the "new" project that removes the necessity to do this.

with this property my old project is rendering properly now.